# GMail - Flag mail as important via JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome Extension that should take some actions inside GMail webmail interface.
One of the actions is to mark an e-mail as important, but I'm really struggling to simulate the click() event on the elements needed to achieve this.

To reproduce the problem easier, we can forget the "chrome extension", and just focus on browser console. Inside GMail interface, with an email message opened, simply try to click on "More" icon, and "Mark as Important". I tried many elements (parent, children, eq(0), eq(1), etc...) around the main ones, but nothing seem to trigger the "Mark as important" option.

Right now, what I found that works for the More menu, is:

```
function clickSimulate(element)
{
    var down = new MouseEvent('mousedown');
    var up = new MouseEvent('mouseup');
    element.dispatchEvent(down);
    element.dispatchEvent(up);  
}

clickSimulate($("div[data-tooltip='More']")[0]);
```

The mark as important option still unsuccessful. Anybody has a solution?

*I still considering the use of IMAP or GMail API(not sure what this is) to solve this problem. But some specific actions needed would be better fitted inside a javascript code running into webmail interface. That's why I still insist trying to fix this specific problem (mark as important) using the same solution.*

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by doing:

```
function clickSimulate(element)
{
    var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    
    var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initMouseEvent('mouseup', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    element.dispatchEvent(evt); 
}
```

Calling this function 2 times on the Mark as Important element, works.